# Unable to pass prop back to parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing a simple test where I have a `name` state in the parent component which I update when a button in the child is clicked. But this does not work, and I'm confused on if I'm doing something wrong.

Parent:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Hello from "./Hello";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState();

  const handle = item => {
    setName(item);
  };

  console.log(name);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Hello test={handle} />
      {name}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child:

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onclick={() => this.props.test("TEST")}>Activate Lasers</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Wait, did you mistype the child? It seems to be the same as the parent...

Comment: both the code are same, h

Comment: you just duplicated the code...

Comment: Just post the child component code to see what you are doing wrong here

Comment: My bad, I've edited the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the function as a prop.

```
import React from "react";

export default function App({ handle }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handle('TEST')}>Activate Lasers</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and render the component like

```
<Hello handle={handle} />
```

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

function Hello({ handle }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handle('TEST')}>Activate Lasers</button>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState();

  const handle = item => {
    setName(item);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Hello handle={handle} />
      {name}
    </div>
  );
}


// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React from "react";

export default function App(props) {
 return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => props.test("TEST")}>Activate Lasers </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It should be onClick Secondly you are using `this` which is pointing to stateless component that is undefined and have no property props within it.

Answer (score 1):

**First:**
React events are written in camelCase syntax:

`onClick` instead of `onclick`.

**second**
the keyword `this` in react usually used in-class component, and using it in a functional component to bind it with where you are using it, so now you need to pass the `props` to the child so that you can access the function.
this should work

```
import React from "react";

export default function Hello(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => props.test("TEST")}>Activate Lasers</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and third try to use the same naming for thing :) to be more readable
I hope I helped you